Spring cloud gateway & Open API : ClientCredentials Flow Doesn't Send client_id and client_secret
im using Spring Cloud Gateway and Open API V3, so i  have an issue on my open api UI page, client_id and client_secret are not sent in the request to get access token when using Client Credential Flow olny one fileld is injected (grant_type) :

my openAPI Class Config  :
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                title = "API Gateway",
                version = "1.0",
                description = "API Gateway Documentation"
        )
)

@SecurityScheme(
        name = "oauth2",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
        flows = @OAuthFlows(
                clientCredentials = @OAuthFlow(
                        tokenUrl = "http://localhost:8080/realms/test2/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                        scopes = {
                                @OAuthScope(name = "read", description = "read scope"),
                                @OAuthScope(name = "write", description = "write scope")
                        }
                )
        )
)

public class OpenApiConfig {
}

Maven :
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

Any help please
